# Integrating .catch after function

Tags: javascript

I have never used .catch before, and the docs I have read online have not made much sense.

With this line:

```
steve.open(req.params.url).then(function(site) {
```

I am getting this error:

```
This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().
```

I have never used .catch before. Can anyone help?

I know after my `.then({})` I should add a add a `.catch((e) => { do something with error })`

But what would this look like after that line? I can't seem to get it working

Comment: Hi Max, `.catch` is part of the promises API. It can take a little while to wrap your head around the using promises. Check out this [guide](https://web.dev/promises/) to JavaScript promises or search for "JavasScript promise tutorial" for lots more!

Answer (score 2):

You can either chain a call to `.catch()` after your existing code:

```
steve.open(req.params.url)
     .then(response => { 
         // Do something...
     })
     .catch(error => { 
         // Handle the error... 
     });
```

Or you can declare the error callback in your call to `.then()`:

```
steve.open(req.params.url)
     .then(response => { 
         // Do something... 
     }, error => { 
         // Handle the error... 
     });
```

There is a slight difference: chaining multiple calls to `.then()` will have different error handling behavior depending on whether you provide error callbacks in the individual calls or whether you call `.catch()` at the end of the chain.

Promises are a complicated topic, I'd suggest reading more about them in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).